# OpenGL ES color errors with MIX function in Android

Tags: android, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

[image]

in opengl es program i input two textures and use fragment shader:

```
        varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
        varying vec2 textureCoordinate2;
        uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
        uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
        uniform lowp float intensity;
        void main() {
            highp vec4 newColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture2,textureCoordinate2);
            highp vec4 vColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate); 
            newColor.r = newColor.r + vColor.r * (1.0 - newColor.a);
            newColor.g = newColor.g + vColor.g * (1.0 - newColor.a);
            newColor.b = newColor.b + vColor.b * (1.0 - newColor.a);
            gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(vColor.rgb, newColor.rgb, 0.86), newColor.a);
        };
```

but the result have some "error color" here, how to fix this?

Comment: Add the shader logs

Comment: @Zoe How to get shader logs?

Comment: Compile them and print if there is a log

Comment: I doubt those sort of artifacts relate to the contents of your shader. I think that one of your textures contains garbage (test that theory by modifying your shader to display one of the textures at a time - don't forget to visualizing the alpha channel too) or perhaps something is up with the framebuffer - e.g. perhaps you're blending with some garbage in the framebuffer, or perhaps one of your textures is the framebuffer itself (that's not allowed)

Comment: @Columbo Each filter in gpuimage's filter group is rendered to the corresponding FBO texture, and the input to each texture is the output of the previous FBO rendering texture. In my GL program has a texture is the output of a FBO,  is not feasible?

Comment: @Zoe I try to Log the detail of the shader program, but nothing output

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your response. If you're 'ping-ponging' that's fine, if you are binding the same image as both input and output during the draw call, then that is definitely your problem. There is some discussion here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57533/workaround-for-reading-and-writing-same-texture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself, this is because I write and read from a same FBO texture, and now I change it and work fine!